# awk command to read log file and add up values in log entries

Tags: bash, awk

I'm running the following command to scan a log file and print out the lines that contain the patterns I specified. At the end of the printed out lines, this line of code also provides a count of the lines (that has the patterns) at the end of the output.

```
awk 'BEGIN{count=0} /error/ && /database/ {print ; count++ } END { print count }' ${LOGFILE}
```

The log file content has content similar to the following:

```
Sep 25 20:18:21 accountsd[377]: notify name LTNCY=200 "SYDRemotePreferencesSourceDidChangeExternally" has been registered 120 times - this may be a leak 
Sep 25 20:18:21 accountsd[377]: notify name LTNCY=200 "com.apple.syncdefaultsd.daemon.wake" has been registered 120 times - this may be a leak
```

What I'm having trouble with is, i have a new situation I need to take into account.

1. I need to also make sure the lines contain the pattern `LTNCY=`
2. Get the count of the number of lines containing the `LTNCY` pattern
3. Then I need to get all the values of each `LTNCY` from each log line
4. Add up all the LTNCY values from step #3 and divide them by step #2

I got as far as this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{count=0} /notify.*LTNCY=/ && /may be a leak/ {print ; count++ } END { print count }' ${LOGFILE}
```

I know a variation of the following command will need to be used:

```
awk  '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

But I'm having trouble combining everything into ONE awk command.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but for log files take a look at Splunk.  Its free to use for log up to 500MB/day.  You get another way to look at log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
/LTNCY/{
  count++
  match($0,/LTNCY=[^ ]*/)
  sum+=substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)+0
}
END{
  print "Sum of LTNCY value is:" sum ORS "Total count of LTYNCY is:" count ORS "Their divide is:" sum/count
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: this looks like it might work.  but the position of the LTNCY pattern seems to be hardcoded in the 6th field.  what happens if that changes in the log? that's a possibility.  how do we account for that?

Comment: @user2831586, In code it is not hard coded so it should work then also, cheers.

Comment: You don't need the `+0` at the end of the `sum+=` line. You should test for count being non-zero before doing `sum/count` in the END and you should be doing `+0`s there or using `printf "%d"`s to ensure numeric (instead of null string) output even when no LTNCY lines are present in the input.

Comment: @EdMorton could you please update the code to do what you're suggesting?

Comment: Though this answer will work too, those are code improvements suggested by Ed sir just FYI.